# JavaFX: Zoom and Scroll do not work properly

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar, zooming

I have the following structure:

```
ScrollPane
   Pane
       A set of children as ImageView
```

The following class I got from (will add the link later, can't find it right now)

```
public class ZoomController extends ScrollPane{

    private int deltaCount = 0;
    private final double DEFAULT_ZOOM = 1.0;
    private DoubleProperty zoomMax = new SimpleDoubleProperty(10.0);
    private DoubleProperty zoomMin = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.1);
    private DoubleProperty zoomDelta = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.2);
    private DoubleProperty zoom = new SimpleDoubleProperty(DEFAULT_ZOOM);
    GroupController gc;
    public ZoomController(Node content) {
        super();
        zoom.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) {
                System.out.println("Zoom=" + zoom.doubleValue());

                content.scaleXProperty().bind(zoom);
                content.scaleYProperty().bind(zoom);
                content.translateXProperty();
            }
        });

        content.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
            public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
                if (event.getDeltaY() > 0) {
                    zoomIn();
                } else {
                    zoomOut();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void zoomIn() {
        double zoomValue = DEFAULT_ZOOM * Math.pow(zoomDelta.get(), deltaCount + 1);
        System.out.println("Zoooom " + zoomValue);
        if (zoomValue > zoomMax.get()) {
            setZoom(zoomMax.get());
            return;
        }

        deltaCount++;
        setZoom(zoomValue);

    }

    public void zoomOut() {
        double zoomValue = DEFAULT_ZOOM * Math.pow(zoomDelta.get(), deltaCount - 1);
        System.out.println("Zoooom " + zoomValue);
        if (zoomValue < zoomMin.get()) {
            setZoom(zoomMin.get());
            return;
        }

        deltaCount--;
        setZoom(zoomValue);
    }

    public void setZoom(double zoomValue) {
        zoom.set(zoomValue);
    }
}
```

and below line crease the object:

```
zoomController = new ZoomController(pane);
```

When I am zooming in, there is a very strange behavior- when I zoom in, scroll bars on the sides do not appear. How to make these bars to appear?

As I understand, the zoom in changes the size of the inner panel and when it grows bigger than the scroll panel, on the scroll pane must appear side bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scale` properties are not taken into account in the size calculation for the content of the `ScrollPane`. To fix this, the content can be wrapped in a `Group`. Furthermore actually setting the content *could* help. BTW you shouldn't establish a binding inside a listener to the source of that binding. Either create a binding to that property

```
content.scaleXProperty().bind(zoom);
content.scaleYProperty().bind(zoom);
```

or set the value inside a listener:

```
zoom.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number newZoom) {
        System.out.println("Zoom=" + newZoom.doubleValue());
        content.setScaleX(newZoom.doubleValue());
        content.setScaleY(newZoom.doubleValue());
    }
});
```

```
public class ZoomController extends ScrollPane {

    private int deltaCount = 0;
    private final double DEFAULT_ZOOM = 1.0;
    private DoubleProperty zoomMax = new SimpleDoubleProperty(10.0);
    private DoubleProperty zoomMin = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.1);
    private DoubleProperty zoomDelta = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.2);
    private DoubleProperty zoom = new SimpleDoubleProperty(DEFAULT_ZOOM);

    public ZoomController(Node content) {
        super(new Group(content));

        zoom.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number newZoom) {
                System.out.println("Zoom=" + newZoom.doubleValue());
                content.setScaleX(newZoom.doubleValue());
                content.setScaleY(newZoom.doubleValue());
            }
        });

        content.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
            public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
                if (event.getDeltaY() > 0) {
                    zoomIn();
                } else {
                    zoomOut();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```